# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U4'), dtype('int64')) -> None (error)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, boxplot

I am trying to create a box plot for the revs per mile for the Audi, Hyundai, Suzuki and Toyota
car manufacturers however, I am picking up the below error which I have not encountered before:

"UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U4'), dtype('int64')) -> None"

Below is my code:

```
 car_data_1 = car_data[(car_data["Manufacturer"] == "Audi") | (car_data["Manufacturer"] == "Hyundai") | 
    (car_data["Manufacturer"] == "Suzuki") | (car_data["Manufacturer"] == "Toyota")]

  plt.boxplot(car_data_1.groupby("Manufacturer")["Rev.per.mile"], labels=["Audi", "Hyundai",    "Suzuki", "Toyota"])
 plt.title("Revs per mile for Audi, Hyundai, Suzuki and Toyota cars")
 plt.xlabel("Car Manufacturer")
 plt.ylabel("Revs per mile")
 plt.show()
```

Below is the dataset:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSyMY.png)

I have tried changing the data type but still receiving the same error

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U4'), dtype('int64')) -> None

Comment: These are the data types:

Comment: object
Manufacturer           object
Model                  object
Type                   object
Min.Price             float64
Price                 float64
Max.Price             float64
MPG.city                int64
MPG.highway             int64
AirBags                object
DriveTrain             object
Cylinders              object
EngineSize            float64
Horsepower              int64
RPM                     int64
Rev.per.mile            int64
Man.trans.avail        object
Fuel.tank.capacity    float64